# Streaming h264 encoded frame over vlc

Tags: encoding, streaming, h.264

I have integrated a TI lib for .h264 encoding on davinci board with processor dm6446
I could verify the encoded bit stream when saved on hdd and using Elecard stream analyser.
But i could not stream it over rtsp and view in vlc player.  The VLC player would switch to TCP/IP and then stop showing message as nothing to play. On further debugging i found out that each encoded bit stream generated is of type `IVIDEO_IDR_FRAME` .

The Nal header for each frame is  like

```
00 00 00 01 67 42 80 1E DA 05 c7 D9 74 00 00 00 01 68 CE 3c 80 00 00 00 01 65
```

As I understand `00 00 00 01` are used as a delimiter and `67` and `68` are for SPS and PPS respectively.  After streaming first two frames as is, I tried to stream the next frames from  the data `00 00 00 01 65`.  But still VLC player could not play the encoded stream. It showed the message at found PPS and stoped there.

What should i do to resolve this issue. I am quite newbee to this field